# 2.81 Render an armature like OpenGL in 2.79

Tags: rendering, armature, opengl

Is it possible to render armature bones in 2.81, like it was in 2.79 with OpenGL?

Comment: Currently the description is a bit unclear. Do you mean "Render with OpenGL" as in rendering the viewport (*View > Viewport Render Image* in 2.8x) or the way the bone shape is displayed in the 3D view?

Comment: lol, I hope he means the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**3D Space View Menu**

In the *`View`* menu of the 3d view

[image]

which calls operator

```
bpy.ops.render.opengl(...)
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: @joshsanfelici if the answer solved your problem, you may want to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Robert, I did it, maybe there's some refresh delay.

Comment: @joshsanfelici Perhaps it mistakenly toggled?